# Nginx force redirect https://www.domain to https://domain

Tags: ubuntu, redirect, nginx, gunicorn

Basically, I'm trying to redirect users from:

- domain.com
- www.domain.com
- http://domain.com
- http://www.domain.com
- https://domain.com
- https://www.domain.com

to https://domain.com/ always. My current Nginx config is as follows:

```
upstream app_server {
  # Bindings to the Gunicorn server
  server 127.0.0.1:8002 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    server_name "~^www\.(.*)$" ;
    return 301 https://$1$request_uri ;
}

server {
  # Access Logs
  access_log path_to/nginx-access.log;
  error_log path_to/nginx-error.log;

  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name _;

  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 5;
  root another_path;

  ssl_certificate path_to.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key path_to.key;

 location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    if (!-f $request_filename) {
      proxy_pass http://app_server;
      break;
    }
  }
  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  location = /500.html {
    root %(PROJECT_PATH)s/templates/public;
  }
}
```

The problem is that my certificate is only valid with domain.com (not with www prefix), so the user gets an error when the last address is accessed (https://www.domain.com).

What am I missing? How can I redirect https://www.domain.com to https://domain.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue here is that you're not catching https://www.domain.com in your first server block. If you exclude the `listen` directive, that server block will listen on 80 by default.

Create another server block for this special case as follows:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2 deffered;
    server_name www.domain.com;
    return 301 https://domain.com$request_uri;
}
```